# How aggressively should I subclass to keep DRY?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

This question occurred to me when an [answer was proposed to another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530928/reusing-a-column-for-a-required-property-with-entity-framework-6-fluent-api-an/20535424?noredirect=1#20535424). Suppose I have a base class

```
public abstract class BaseClass {}
```

with some decent number of derived classes- let's say more than half a dozen. Most of those derived classes share no similarity beyond what they inherit from the base class, but two of them have a similarity like so

```
public class OneOfMyDerivedClasses : BaseClass
{
    public string SimilarProperty {get; set;}
    //Other implementation details
}

public class AnotherOneOfMyDerivedClasses : BaseClass
{
    public string SimilarProperty {get; set;}
    //Other implementation details, dissimilar to those in OneOfMyDerivedClasses
}
```

That's it. That's the only similarity that any of the subclasses share beyond what was inherited from `BaseClass`. In my actual application I've solved this with an interface `IHaveSimilarProperty` defining the single `SimilarProperty` property, as all I care about is that an object implements said interface in use. But since I have duplication, should I be defining an intermediate base class for these two derived classes to inherit from, ie

```
public abstract IntermediateBaseClass : BaseClass
{
    public string SimilarProperty {get; set;}
}
```

I could also combine both approaches, decorating the intermediate class with the interface...

So my question is around whether or not this is sufficient duplication to warrant an intermediate base class in terms of OOP best practices. Should I aggressively eliminate all duplication at every turn or should I take a more pragmatic approach? If the latter, what are the rules of thumb that would push me to choose one approach over the other?

Comment: Do you need polymorphism in this scenario?

Comment: I think this is going to be largely opinion based without a concrete example. Personally I base my design decisions on what the objects represent rather than their properties. That was should requirements change your code is more adaptable.

Comment: I'd say that no, this scenario does not warrant another base class.  If using an interface works for the requirements, then it's better not to over-engineer.

Comment: A sort of vague rule of thumb that you might find useful is: if you can't think of an appropriate name for this "intermediate" class, or for an interface, then it may also be too early to introduce it.

Comment: @odyss-jii it sounds like a good rule, but I struggle with appropriate names for all of my classes and interfaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any design pattern can be taken to extremes.  Here's some general guidelines I would use when deciding whether or not to subclass:

- Is the amount of code relatively large (>10 lines)?
- Will the code require periodic changes (e.g. business rules)
- Will I need to use polymorphism (does it make sense to use the *base* class or interface instead of one of the subclasses)

In your case, since the only similarity seems to be a property with the same *name* in both classes, it probably isn't worth it to subclass.

Comment: Not only is it not "worth it" to subclass, it's flat-out wrong to do so if the subclass isn't really representing a specialized version of the base class.  "Re-use" should never in and of itself be the reason for subclassing.

Answer (score 4):

You should decide on subclassing based on the common semantic of your classes, not merely on their common attributes. Sharing a common property is not enough to warrant an intermediate common subclass, but sharing a common semantics would definitely be enough.

Here is an example: a `Rectangle` and a `Circle` classes may have a property called `Center`, but it does not mean that the two classes should have a common subclass (apart from the abstract `Shape`, which may not necessarily have a `Center`). In this situation, an interface `IWithCenter` fits a lot better. Similarly, a `Label` and an `TextField` may have a property `Text`, but in this case even a common interface would be unwarranted.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to aggressively eliminate duplication at every turn, but your #1 tool for doing so is *composition*, not inheritance.  Use inheritance when you need polymorphism, use composition when you need reuse.

...but if the "duplication" in question is just one property, then maybe don't worry about it.  The golden rule of refactoring is that each refactoring should make your life better instead of worse.  If it doesn't, you're doing it wrong.